# Group no mysql junto com o join

Tags: php, mysql, join

Tenho uma tabela de alunos e uma tabela de pais.
Um aluno pode estar associado a até três pais.

```
SELECT 
      a.idAluno,
      a.matriculaAluno,
      a.nomeAluno,
      a.sexoAluno,
      a.dataNascAluno,
      b.id,
      b.matricula,
      b.cpf,
      b.nome 
    FROM 
      alunos a 
      LEFT JOIN matriculas b 
      ON a.matriculaAluno = b.matricula 
    WHERE 
      a.status = 1 AND b.status = 1 
     GROUP by 
        b.cpf
```

O retorno é :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Gostaria que não se repetisse os registros iguais da primeira tabela. 
E quero que a tabela matriculas venha na pesquisa agrupada.

Ou seja, para cada registro de aluno venham agrupados os três registros de responsáveis, pois cada aluno pode ter 3 responsáveis no máximo.

Answer (score 0):

Para não repetir a primeira coluna seia necessário um group by de idAluno e tirar o group by de cpf. Normalmente cpfs são únicos e não faz muito sentido um group by neles porém se perderia os cpfs diferentes ao se dar um group by no idAluno o que me parece errado é esses valores pois ids iguais para alunos diferentes não faz sentido. Por fim para trazer a matricula bastaria fazer no select um *.matricula

```
SELECT 
      b.*,
      a.idAluno,
      a.matriculaAluno,
      a.nomeAluno,
      a.sexoAluno,
      a.dataNascAluno,
      b.id,
      b.matricula,
      b.cpf,
      b.nome 
    FROM 
      alunos a 
      LEFT JOIN matriculas b 
      ON a.matriculaAluno = b.matricula 
    WHERE 
      a.status = 1 AND b.status = 1 
     GROUP by 
        a.idAluno
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema de agrupar pelo IdAluno é que o retorno será apenas o primeiro, ignorando os outros responsáveis. O fato é que não é um problema repetirem as primeiras informações da tabela, sendo q as outras vão vir diferentes, basta ignorá-las no tratamento da informação. O seu select já está certo.